# Why use Ubuntu for PHP

Tags: 12.04

After doing some research on google i found that most of the company is using LAMP for php development. Is there any big advantage using ubuntu for php?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking...  The L in LAMP is for Linux, and Ubuntu is a Linux-distro.  Ubuntu is relatively easy to use, often updated, have a huge number of users and is well supported - so it's certainly not a disadvantage to chose Ubuntu when choosing a distro for doing LAMP.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ubuntu as your LAMP environment en your development environment is purely of personal taste.

What would you like to compare Ubuntu to? It also depends on what tools you want to use for PHP development. Some or not available on Ubuntu, others have a higher learning curve.

Learn more about Ubuntu by starting at [Meet Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop).

Answer (score 0):

**LAMP** is:

**Linux**  any variety but why not Ubuntu

**Apache** a well known web server

**MySQL** database software

**Perl, Python** or **PHP** a scripting language

LAMP is not an alternative to Ubuntu but a set of programs run together on Ubuntu or other Linux OS.

`Is there any big advantage using ubuntu for php?`

No, PHP is a well defined standard so any platform that implements it correctly will work.  Ubuntu implements it correctly but so do many others.  However, there is no reason not to use Ubuntu either.  Lots of people use Ubuntu as the **L** in there **LAMP**.

[see this Wikipedia page for more information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29)